# Cannot connect using WebSockets, not changing readyState

Tags: php, sockets, javascript

Ive tried several approaches and even copy/pasted from http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Im using Google Chrome 5.0.375.70 beta and the error is always the same: 
Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

when debugging I see the readyState is always 0 (connecting), no other error is shown.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 2 supported Drafts of the WebSocket API in the wild.

**Draft75** which is the one that is supported by the linked PHP script, and **[Draft76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76)** which requires a different Upgrade Header and Handshake, another one **Draft77** is also finished and may suddenly and up being implement by a Browser.

Somewhere between Version 5 and 6 of Chrome they did the switch from **Draft75** to **Draft76**.

As far as I can see here, the PHP Script does not terminate the connection when it receives an invalid upgrade header. Therefore Chrome will still wait for the Handshake, which explains while the ReadyState does not change.

Comment: Thanks, think it was just the handshake failing. I moved to using NodeJS so this is no longer a problem for me, still, thank you!

Comment: btw, here's a shameless plug for my own websocket server ;-)  http://code.google.com/p/web-socks/