# Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 with php websockets

Tags: php, javascript, html, websocket, phpwebsocket

basically it is a rehash of this question:
[Cannot connect using WebSockets, not changing readyState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012623/cannot-connect-using-websockets-not-changing-readystate)

Which was not really answered.

I see on the server side:

```
[nlubin@localhost www]$ php -q /var/www/html/realTime/server/startDaemon.php
2011-03-15 13:49:30 System: Socket Resource id #7 created.
2011-03-15 13:49:30 System: Socket bound to localhost:7332.
2011-03-15 13:49:30 System: Start listening on Socket.
```

I am using the client and socket from this [NetTuts: start using html5 websockets today](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/)
When i first go to the client it says in the box `Socket Status: 0`
and the server says:

```
2011-03-15 13:51:53 WebSocket: Resource id #8 CONNECTED!
2011-03-15 13:51:53 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2011-03-15 13:51:53 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2011-03-15 13:51:53 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
```

Then when i send anything it says: "Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11"

If i click disconnect it disconnects..

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure your server/browser implement the same version of the websocket draft specification.

check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets for the implementation status of your browser. If you are using chrome, your browser is most probably in draft-76.

In the comment section of the tutorial you are using someone says the tutorial uses the draft-75.

the comment mentions this other tutorial : http://bohuco.net/blog/2010/07/html5-websockets-example/ which is implementing draft-76

I hope this will help you,

Jerome Wagner

Comment: follow the second tutorial (bohuco) and you will have a draft-76 compatible server. I highly suspect your problem comes from an incompatibility between browser / server.

Comment: i applied what is in that tutorial and it did nothing. still does not work

Comment: ok now the tutorial is opening the connection. but im not getting the correct responses

Comment: cool if it did the trick. so you think it was due to this draft-75 versus draft-76 problem ?

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error when I was trying to send a message through websocket before it was connected.  Make sure your sending logic is triggered in websocket's `.onopen` handler (or after it).